# wildcard for single digit mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use the LIKE operator to match possible values in a column.

If the value begins with "CU" followed by a digit (e.g. "3") followed by anything else, I would like to return it. There only seems to be a wildcard for any single character using underscore, however I need to make sure it is a digit and not a-z.
I have tried these to no avail:

```
select name from table1 where name like 'CU[0-9]%'
select name from table1 where name like 'CU#%'
```

Preferably this could be case sensitive i.e. if cu or Cu or cU then this would not be a match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use regexp:

```
select name
from table1
where name regexp binary '^CU[0-9]'
```

The documentation for `regexp` is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html).

EDIT: `binary` is required to ensure case-sensitive matching

Answer (score 9):

The [`like` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) only have the `%` and `_` wildcards in MySQL, but you can use a regular expression with the [`rlike` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html):

```
select name from table1 where name rlike '^CU[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEXP operator, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

so your query would be:

```
select name from table where name regexp 'CU[0-9].*';
```

Comment: smuk - because the regexp doesn't anchor to the beginning of the string with the caret (`^`) it will also match values like `ABCU1` and `xxxxxxxCU3yyyy`.

Comment: Ed is correct, assuming he meant "without" and not "with". Adding `^` to the start is what I need. The `.*` was not required

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
select name from table where name between 'CU0' and 'CU9'
```

Comment: that's close but it won't match something like `CU9AX`.